# Python regex: get words that are between given word and the closest character

Tags: python, string

I have a dataset that looks like this

| ID | Details |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | he wants to invest, Project: Emaar, budget [] |
| 2 | she is interested in renting, Project: W Residence, bedrooms=2 |
| 3 | wants to sell, Project: Dubai View; callback |

I need to extract project name, which is located between a word 'Project:' and closet character (for e.x. , | ;)

So that in the result it looks like this:

| ID | Details |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Emaar |
| 2 | W Residence |
| 3 | Dubai View |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the comma & semi-colon are always at the end of the project name and your projects only have letters & spaces in their names, then you could use this regex:

```
Project: ([A-Za-z ]+)[;,]
```

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/IGSKPc/1).

Answer (score 1):

If the pattern is Project: (something) comma or semi-colon, you can use the following RegEx:  `(?<=Project:\s).*(?=,|;)`